# java socket client to server1 to server2

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, port

I am new to java socket programming. I have done an application server where, client send message("hi") to server1 and server1 pass the message(hi) to server2.

Is it possible to share the same port? Since server1 and server2 is listening for message.

Or any better way? Thanks

Comment: If 'client2' is listening in the TCP sense it is a server not a client. You don't state which port you want to share. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, client2 is a server. I currently using two port 5432 and 5433.

Comment: I used port 5432 to listen from client1 then close() and start port 5433 and send the message.

Comment: Come on, there are two servers and two ports here, which uses what? and why do you close one port and open another?

Comment: Client1 creates the message and send to Server1 using port 5432, then Server1 receives the message and close port 5432 and send it to Server2 using port 5433.

Comment: I used two port because both server has to be online at the same time

Comment: So why doesn't server1 just use port 5422 all the time, and server2 use 5423? There's no need for server1 to close its listening port at all. To answer your question, two processes in the same host can't normally share a TCP port.

Comment: I need both server1 and server2 running before the client send the message so I used two ports and I wouldn't sure whether I am doing it correctly. Thanks